# "Missing retina 4-inch launch image" error, but I I have that image

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, iphone-5, asset-catalog

The following error appears when I run my iOS app on Xcode 5. I have added an image for the retina 4-inch iOS6 version through the asset catalog and the app runs without problem on my iPhone 5 and in the simulator.

[image: Received error message]

So why am I getting this error message and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the default image in project bundle to get ride of this issue(By default the image will be created).

[image]

Comment: Ok, so that worked. Strange though that I have to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working on iPhone5 app then you have to use Default-568@2x.png because of retina display.