# Unable to get rid of "An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 7.0 and later is required" error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I'm designing an iOS app and am trying to add launch screens. Although I'm only supporting iOS 9.0 and later, I've added launch screen for iOS 6.0 and later. Despite this, for some reason I'm still getting the following error:

"An iPhone Retina (4-inch) launch image for iOS 7.0 and later is required"

When the add the pictures and save, the error temporarily goes away. But when I run the app on any device (through Simulator), the error comes back. Also, no launch screen shows.

***YES, I know there are several threads on Stackoverflow (examples given at the end) mentioning this error***. I've looked through them and the don't help me because they were either for an older version of Xcode, or the problem wasn't exactly as the one I have.

**I am using Xcode 7.3.1 with Swift 2.2**

[image]

[image]

Examples of other threads with similar issues:

[XCode iOS7 Asset Catalog Warning - Only Supporting iOS8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700534/xcode-ios7-asset-catalog-warning-only-supporting-ios8)

[How do I clear a warning for xcassets unassigned children?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189633/how-do-i-clear-a-warning-for-xcassets-unassigned-children)

[Adding iOS 7 version of iPhone 4-inch launch image to project breaks launch image when run on iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19732975/adding-ios-7-version-of-iphone-4-inch-launch-image-to-project-breaks-launch-imag)

["Missing retina 4-inch launch image" error, but I I have that image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19422662/missing-retina-4-inch-launch-image-error-but-i-i-have-that-image)

[Missing Retina 4 launch image. How to ignore this error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596991/missing-retina-4-launch-image-how-to-ignore-this-error)

Comment: You only have an iPad launch image for ios 7 and later, add the iPhone one

Comment: Why not take the opportunity to migrate to a launch storyboard and never have to deal with this again?

Answer (score 3):

You have selected the configuration for the "Universal" devices but not added any image for iPhone for iOS 7 and later.

You can do this two things to get rid of this error:-

1. If you are aiming to deploy the app for iOS 8 and / or iOS 9 and later, just select the iOS 8 and later in the properties of "Brand Assets-2". By this you can solve this error.
2. If you want to keep this app for iOS 7, then just select the "Portrait" mode in iOS 7 and later and insert image into it.

By this two ways you can get rid off to your error.

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend switching to a Launch Screen storyboard. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this was make available in Xcode 6.